# How to create file object from URL object (image)

Tags: java

I need to create a File object from URL object
My requirement is 
 I need to create a file object of a web image (say googles logo)

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/pathtoaimage.jpg");
File f = create image from url object
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would also recommend looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) and check if it does the job for you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can make use of [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) in order to load the image from an URL and then write it to a file. Something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/pathtoaimage.jpg");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
File file = new File("downloaded.jpg");
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
```

This also allows you to convert the image to some other format if needed.

Comment: Is their any way to create file object from BufferedImage with out writing it to disk

Comment: A file by definition needs to be stored on some file system. You would need some in-memory file system in order to end up with a file that is not persisted.

Comment: did you notice accepted answer ? i don't know FileUitls whether creates a temp file for that :P

Comment: My feeling is that your requirement needs some second thought... Namely, assuming you need to call a method like `processImage(File f)`, this should be changed to `processImage(BufferedImage img)` or `processImage(InputStream is)`. Either of these changes would spare you of storing external images on the local FS.

Comment: Regarding the accepted answer, `FileUtils` needs a `File` instance (as you may have noticed), the same as the `ImageIO` API does. If you'll choose to create a temporary file, that will still be persisted, but deleted on JVM exit (and/or created in the system tmp directory). So from this point of view, the two answers are exactly the same. :P

Comment: this saved my day after more than 4 hrs of debugging. Thanks

Answer (score 95):

Use [Apache Common IO's `FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);
```

The method downloads the content of `url` and saves it to `f`.

Comment: This worked for me:
`URL url = new URL("http://www.mydomain.com/pathToFile/fileName.pdf");
String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
String path = tDir + "tmp" + ".pdf";
file = new File(path);
file.deleteOnExit();
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);`

Comment: @AdrienBe `FileUtils` gets an error in Eclipse, it doesn't show an import.

Comment: `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` should do the job, see link to library in answer

Comment: And `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.toFile(URL url)` in case we just want to convert `URL` to `File`.

Comment: Note: add `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'` to gradle dependencies block

Answer (score 66):

Since Java 7

```
File file = Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile();
```

Comment: This is for retrieving the file location, with the `file://` protocol for exemple, not sure if the OP wanted the location or download the image itself, but anyways this is what I was looking for personally. thanks

Comment: This causes a URISyntaxException if the URL has any spaces in it as might likely be the case if the URL uses a `file://` protocol.

Comment: Spaces should be replaced by: `%20`

Answer (score 16):

You can convert the `URL` to a `String` and use it to create a new `File`. e.g.

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/pathtoaimage.jpg");
File f = new File(url.getFile());
```

Comment: When using this method for local file system files that have a space in the full path, %20 will not get converted to space automatically and may cause an exception

Comment: url.getFile attaches the query (say, ?a=b&c=d), if any. Usually moot since there is usually no query. However, to get just the file, one should use url.getPath()

Comment: Neither getFile or getPath does proper decoding, so the Paths.get() approach just above is preferable,

Comment: @byxor -- since you've corrected your mistake, is there any value in keeping your two comments? If not, remove. I'll remove my comment when you do.

Answer (score 14):

In order to create a File from a HTTP URL you need to download the contents from that URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.ro/logos/2011/twain11-hp-bg.jpg");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("downloaded.jpg"));
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
while (true) {
    int len = in.read(buf);
    if (len == -1) {
        break;
    }
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The downloaded file will be found at the root of your project: {project}/downloaded.jpg