# How to Use URL by replacing File Storage path in Android

Tags: android, url, google-cloud-print, android-print-framework, android-pdf-api

I am Printing Pdf using Google Cloud Printing from my Storage of my phone. i want to use pdf URL by replacing this. How to use URL? 
For Example: i want to replace                                                                     /print/test.pdf"      to "www.example.com/print/test.pdf"

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/print/test.pdf");
       Intent printIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrintDialogActivity.class);
       printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
       printIntent.putExtra("title", "Android print demo");
         startActivity(printIntent);
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324862/how-to-create-file-object-from-url-object) post. I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar and paste it to your libs folder in Android Studio. Open your Gradle file and inside the dependencies add this  "**compile files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')**"

```
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
                String path = tDir + "tmp" + ".pdf";
                File file = new File(path); file.deleteOnExit();

                try {
                    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent printIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        PrintDialogActivity.class);
                printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                        "application/pdf");
                printIntent.putExtra("title", "Android print demo");
                startActivity(printIntent);
```